# Retrieve SQL data and place into JSwing Table

Tags: java, sql

I have a database that contains both live and completed Jobs.

I want to create a GUI that people can use to filter their own jobs. (IE - user enters employee ID and it retrieves all Jobs (both live and completed) they've submitted).

So far, I have a PreparedStatement....

as follows:

```
AnalystJobs = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM cases WHERE EmployeeID = + 'EmployeeID'");
```

The statement appears to work, but I'm unsure how to print the data into the JSwing Table.

On researching, it appears I have to use `ResultSet rs = st.getResultSet();`

And then something on the lines of : `String userName = rs.getString(2);`

Comment: You should use String userName = rs.getString(2);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get all the required fields like below

something on the lines of : `String userName = rs.getString(2);`

Put it to some Collection and add that collection to JTable.

Comment: What does 2 refer to. The column within the database?

Comment: You can use the field name like `rs.getString('firstname')` and so on.

Comment: Thank you Ketan. You mention "some collection", are you referring to this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html

Comment: I'll look into ArrayList, thanks. With regards to collecting the data, what would be the better way to loop it. At the moment, I have it printing out the data from the database - but it only prints one record. (ie - if one employee is related to several jobs).

Comment: I think you have single record right now in your resultset as query is `"SELECT * FROM cases WHERE EmployeeID = + 'EmployeeID'"` If you have query like `select * from cases` then you will have resultset with multiple records and you can do like `while(rs.next())`

Comment: I've sorted it by replacing the 'IF' with a 'While'. Probably a very bad way to code, but it works.